# chartjs tooltip repeats multiple times when hovering on a bar after checkbox selection

Tags: chart.js

I have a stacked horizontal bar chart with a series of checkboxes to hide and show certain types of bars on the chart. When a checkbox is checked or unchecked, I'm passing a fresh new dataset to the chart. It all works but after checking a box to make a type visible, the tooltips on the bars affected are repeated multiple times. For example, instead of showing this tooltip:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

I'm getting:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

I've inspected the data and it's only showing 3 lines but the chart is repeating them. Any ideas?

**Update:**

The issue occurs in the tooltip label callback. After hiding or showing some bars on the chart based on checkbox selections, the label callback fires more than once in some cases when hovering over a bar. So 'Some text' occurs two or more times sometimes.

```
plugins: {
    legend: {
        display: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        displayColors: false,
        callbacks: {
            title: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                tooltipItem[0].label = '';
                return;
            },
            label: (context) => {
                return 'Some text';
            }
        }
    }
}
```